# Genetic Algorithm A.I. repetitive behavior

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, simulation, bots, genetic-algorithm

I am writing a C# Windows Forms Application which simulates a simple environment (grid) with two types of objects: plants and herbivores. The herbivores have neural networks which take contents the surrounding few cells as input that decide which direction to move in. The idea is to train the herbivores to eat the plants using a fitness function and a genetic algorithm.

My **problem** is that if there is nothing surrounding a herbivore, it will decide to move in a particular direction, then, if there is still nothing around it, it will move in the same direction again. What I end up with is a few herbivores that just move in strait lines and never actually encounter any plants at all.

Would adding a **clock signal** as an input (with each bit as an individual input to the neural network) change this behavior or is this not recommended? I have also thought about adding an input which is just random data (from a Gaussian distribution) to add some unpredictability, but I don't know if this would help or harm the problem. Another idea I am not sure about is if maybe having inputs for the past few moves (as a sort of memory) might solve this issue.

Comment: Does GA optimize weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a [Recurrent Network](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/). You can keep track of the last N decisions the network has made and then use them as extra inputs to your network so it will have some sort of knowledge about where it was going and for how long. It could at some point evolve in such a way that it starts doing some sort of path finding.

Answer (score 1):

What @Can_Alper said is definitely good. Also take a look at [LSTM's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory).